# Why won't Perl let me chain a postfix loop from a postfix comparison?

Tags: perl, syntax, postfix-operator

This is ok:

```
$foo++ if $condition;
```

And this is ok:

```
$foo++ for (1..10);
```

But this isn't:

```
$foo++ if $condition for (1..10);
```

I find the latter quite readable if things aren't complicated, and it fits on one line!  Is there a way to do this or should I move on with my life?

Comment: Could you capitalize Perl in the title, please? =)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only have one postfix operation per statement. But you can do what you want (sorta) by using a `do` block, e.g.

```
do { $foo++ if $condition } for ( 1..10 );
```

Personally, I find this style extremely confusing and difficult to read. I'd avoid it, if I were you. If you're going to all that trouble, you might as well say

```
for( 1..10 ) { $foo++ if $condition }
```

IMHO.

Comment: It's really all the same to me. I just couldn't find anywhere where that was spelled out and was looking for an explanation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to achieve the same effect as an if statement is with `and`, so you could say

```
$condition and $foo++ for 1 .. 10;
```

However, that is not an encouraged practice.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, this was an intentional design decision in the very early days of perl to avoid having people write hard to read or hard to get right code.  Perl 6 will allow at least some combinations (if/for and for/if, but not for/for or if/if maybe?) and I believe Perl 5 will follow suit at some point.

Update: Perl 6 will allow a conditional inside a loop (e.g. `EXPR if EXPR for LIST` ); anything more requires extra parens (e.g. `( EXPR for LIST ) if EXPR` ).

Comment: Sometimes I think the last thing on Larry Wall and co.'s minds was preventing unreadable code :D That's one of the joys of Perl, though, the freedom to do what works best for the situation.  I'm all for more freedom, even if it gives me a chance to screw myself over.